# how to get input stream from input stream file?

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, spring-mvc, download

I have been developing a java web app and I want to add a download function.
I want to download zip file located in "C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\webapps\xml\XML.zip".
I have converted the file to InputStream, but I'm still confused how to get input stream data from the InputStream?

When I click the download button, it returns 0 (zero) byte of the zip file

Here is the controller to handle download zipfile :

```
@RequestMapping("download")
public String Download(HttpServletResponse response) {

    ZipInputStream zis = null;

    try {           

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\\webapps\\xml\\XML.zip");
        zis = new ZipInputStream(is);

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + "XML.zip" + "\"");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/zip");
        IOUtils.copy(zis.getInputStream, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return null;
}
```

this line is causing the zero byte zip file:

```
IOUtils.copy(**zis.getInputStream**, out);
```

Comment: The path to your file is not quoted ("C:\\apache"). Is that this way in your code?

Comment: I'm puzzled... Why was it important to include a picture of your download button?

Comment: Also, if you want to get the whole ZIP file downloaded, you don't have to use ZipInputStream... That is for accessing _the contents_ of the ZIP file... instead of `zis.getInputStream()` use `is.getInputStream()`, and remove the code related to the ZipInputStream...

Comment: @SJuan76: Im sorry I just forgot to quote the path of file. in my project it has been quoted,
but thank you for your fast response

Comment: @ppeterka66: Im sorry if the button has made you puzzled.
I just removed code related to ZipInputStream but it still get error 'cause getInputStream() can't be called by using InputStream class object

Comment: @yunus Sorry, I forgot to remove that function call. You don't need it, as the FileInputStream instance you have is already a perfectly valid inputstream to use in IOUtils.copy... I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your code compiles:

If you are already picking up a zip file, there is no need to pass it through ZipInputStream again.

something like this
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html

Comment: That's awesome!
Now my code works well.
Thanks very much for your good reply

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the whole ZIP file downloaded, you don't have to use `ZipInputStream`... That is for *accessing the contents* of the ZIP file...

Instead of `zis.getInputStream()` use `is.getInputStream()`, and remove the code related to the `ZipInputStream`:

```
@RequestMapping("download")
public String Download(HttpServletResponse response) {

  //ZipInputStream zis = null; no need for this

  try {           

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\\webapps\\xml\\XML.zip");
    //zis = new ZipInputStream(is); //no need for this

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + "XML.zip" + "\"");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    IOUtils.copy(is, out); //no zis here, and "is" is already an InputStream instance
    out.flush();
    out.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 

  return null;
}
```

Also, I'd revise the .close() calls: they are almost always best fit for `finally` blocks to ensure everzthing gets closed properly. (that, or try-with-resource blocks are to be used.)